How to add a button to jump to an active tab in primevue
<template>
  <div>
    <Button @click="jumpToActiveTab">Jump to Active Tab</Button> 
    <TabView :scrollable="true" previousIcon: { class: 'text-indigo-900 w-8'}>
      <TabPanel v-for="(a, index) in filteredTabledata" :key="index">
        <template #header>
          <span
            :class="[index == activeIndexVal ? 'text-white font-black' : 'text-white font- medium']"
            @click="getDataId(a['_id'], a['Status'])"
          >
            {{ a.Account_id }}
          </span>
        </template>
      </TabView>
    </div>
  </template>
<script>
import TabPanel from 'primevue/tabpanel';
import TabView from 'primevue/tabview';
export default {
  components: {
    TabView,
    TabPanel
  },
  data() {
    tabledata: [],
  },
  computed:{
    filteredTabledata() {
      return this.tabledata.filter(item => String(item.Account_id).startsWith(this.searchQuery));
    }
  },
  methods:{
    getData(){
      axios.get('url').then({
        this.tableData = res.data
      })
    },
    jumpToActiveTab(){
      console.log('jump to active tab')
    }
  }
}
</script>

I used PrimeVue TabView, I want to implement a login in jump to active tab button.
If user clicks the button, it should take user to the active tab page
If user is in the last page but the active tab is in the 1st page means with the single click it must move to the 1st page without navigating by using the prev or next button.

See PrimeVue Documentation
If you have learnt Vue, you can do it in less than 2 minutes.
<TabView v-model:active-index='targetIndex'>

Then add targetIndex into data().
Now this.targetIndex is the index of the active tab. It's reactivity so setting this.targetIndex will change the UI. You can do it.

It is not scrolling back to the active tab, for example I have 100 plus datas and my active tab is Index 0 and I scrolled to 100th tab. So My active Index is 0 and I simply navigated to the last page of the tab now I want to scroll back easily with a single click by avoiding a back navigation button, that is what my requirement is.. But the above approach is not working

@Saravanamms Maybe a minimal reproduction can help solve this
